# How to update product attribute via Magento 2 API

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, rest-api

I'm writing a Magento 2 client library in nodeJS and I've created some product attributes via this [POST API](https://adobe-commerce.redoc.ly/2.4.6-admin/tag/productsattributes#operation/PostV1ProductsAttributes)  **/rest/V1/products/attributes** which worked fine but I want to add update method as well, for which I tried this [PUT API](https://adobe-commerce.redoc.ly/2.4.6-admin/tag/productsattributesattributeCode#operation/PutV1ProductsAttributesAttributeCode) **/rest/V1/products/attributes/{attributeCode}** and it's not letting me update the product attributes as this always returns with error: `Attribute with the same code already exists.`

Yes it exists already, that's why I'm trying to update it. Following is the example request I'm making via Postman.

URL: https://MY_HOST/rest/V1/products/attributes/advantages

Body (JSON):

```
{
"attribute":{
  "frontend_input":"text",
  "attribute_code":"advantages",
  "default_frontend_label":"f max 1"
  }
}
```

It's been many hours now and I still can't figure out why it's not updating, it seems like it tries to insert a new product attribute as I tried to pass attribute code which does not exists in magento and it created a new attribute with that code, which doesn't seems right with PUT method. Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code of the PUT API `/rest/V1/products/attributes/{attributeCode}` endpoint, it appears that the endpoint implementation **requires specifying the `attribute_id` in the body of the request.**

When making a PUT request to update an attribute, you need to provide both the `attributeCode` in the endpoint URL and the `attribute_id` in the request body. The attribute_id serves as a unique identifier for the attribute you want to update. Without this attribute_id, the API assumes that you want to create a new attribute instead of updating an existing one.

It's weird, but that's how it works. :-)

Comment: Thanks @JBrada . It's really weird but it works now :)